# $stateParams returns empty object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using MEANstack. Here is the simple stateparams that returns the empty object. Code :

route.js

```
var app = angular.module('mean-blog.home', [
'ui.router']);
```

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider

```
                .state('organizers', {
            url: '/organizers',
            templateUrl: '/home/templates/organizers.html',
            controller: 'OrganizerCtrl'
        })
                .state('viewprofile', {
            url: '/vieworganizer/:organizerid',
            templateUrl: '/home/templates/viewprofile.html',
            controller: 'viewProfileCtrl'
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

controller.js

```
.controller('viewProfileCtrl', function($scope, Users, $stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams) //returns empty object
})
```

View File

```
 <p> {{organizer._id}}</p>
  <a ui-sref="vieworganizer({organizerid:organizer._id})">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
</a>
```

This ui-sref is also giving me the following error.

```
Error: Could not resolve 'vieworganizer' from state ''
transitionTo@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3140:17
go@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:3068:14
link/</transition<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js:4181:13
f/l<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:138:473
e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:40:72
nf/n.defer/c<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:44:155
```

If i open the direct url

```
http://localhost:3000/vieworganizer/59b8c14ebed9a011bc5acb54
```

it returns empty stateparams object.

Anyone who can help me to solve this issue!

Comment: Your state is called `viewprofile` not `vieworganizer`

Comment: You don't appear to be injecting $stateParams. Shouldn't it be .controller('viewProfileCtrl', ['$scope', 'Users', '$stateParams', function($scope, Users, $stateParams) { ....

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a **`state`** named **`vieworganizer`** , it should be

```
<a ui-sref="viewprofile ({organizerid:organizer._id})">
```

Comment: Thanks,1 issue has been solved. another one is empty stateparams.. Will you help me on this please

Comment: change it as <a ui-sref="viewprofile ({organizerid:'organizer._id'})">

Comment: Error: Could not resolve 'vieworganizer' from state '' issue has been solved as the state name was different. Now the issue is, I am not able to get stateparams value in controller as it returns empty object.

Comment: adding quotes changes its type to string and not able to get variable data, so again empty object and not able to get id as it acts as a string

Comment: did you see if its actually getting the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154315/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-simerjit-parmar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the view file

```
<p> {{organizer._id}}</p>
  <a ui-sref="viewprofile({organizerid:organizer._id})">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit
</a>
```

`viewprofile` is the state which is defined in `app.config` file for url `/vieworganizer/:organizerid`

Comment: solution for empty stateparams?

Comment: have you tried the `$scope.params` instead of `$stateParams` for getting the parameters?